# Telegram Bot API: Download files larger than 20 MB

Tags: go, telegram, telebot

I am using [Telegram Bot Go SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2) to catch three webhooks:

- `telebot.OnPhoto`
- `telebot.OnVideo`
- `telebot.OnDocument`

and I am able to catch these updates successfully. However, as a second step, I want to download this media and upload them to another storage.

I am using [Download function](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2#Bot.Download)

The flow works as expected for files under 20 MB but there is a file size limit for Bot API.

Is there a workaround to download files by their file ID from Telegram? Since files exist in Telegram, I guess there might be another way to download them by their ID.